To sum time to a dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm column
I've got column A in this format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm and I would like to sum an hour to it. I've tried cell L4 =A4 + Time(1, 0, 0) following the Microsoft AI copilot but it gives me an error (looks like the function Time does not exist). I've got Excel 2013

Ensure A4 is not a text.

Also, always include some sample data and the current output in the question.
